# show image in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to render a image from my sqlite3 database, by using this library:

`#!/usr/bin/python3
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from io import BytesIO
    import base64
    @app.route('/show/')
    def show():
        file_data = FileContents.query.filter_by(id=3).first()
        image = b64encode(file_data.data)

        return render_template('display.html', image = image)`

---

and putting this variable in the html:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="data:image;base64,{{image}}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But I can't show the image (I am using python3 and google chorme) can someone help to get it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the extension. Example: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ image }}"\>` 
And decode image to utf-8 `return render_template('display.html', image = image.decode('utf8'))`